# How do I test that forEach is calling savePost three times?

Tags: javascript, arrays, testing, foreach

I am learning how to write tests in JavaScript and I have this code here:

```
function handlePosts() {
    var posts = [
      { id: 23, title: 'Me Gusta JS' },
      { id: 52, title: 'Ciudad Código' },
      { id: 105, title: 'Programar Ya' }
    ];
    
    for (var i = 0; i < posts.length; i++) {
      savePost(posts[i]);
    }
}
```

That calls `savePost` three times, but I am wanting to ensure that when I or someone else utilizes, specifically the `forEach` helper method, that one of my tests looks for the `forEach` actually calling `savePost` three times.

I already developed a test to check that the `forEach` exists, in other words it's being used, as opposed to some other array helper method, but not sure how to test that it's doing what it should be doing.

```
describe('forEach', function() {
    it('forEach method exists', () => {
        expect(forEach).toBeDefined();
    });
    
    it('forEach is calling savePost three times', () => {
        
    });
});
```

I am keen to gain an understanding of how to think about this, rather than just an answer.

I imagine something like `expect(savePost.length).toEqual(3);`, but I am not sure.

Comment: Not sure if this is overkill for your project, but have a look at the `sinon` framework that provides this kind of thing (see `expectation.exactly()`) https://sinonjs.org/releases/v7.2.4/mocks/#expectations

Comment: @DacreDenny, the sinon framework could work as a guide. It will have to do. Feel free to share your comment as an answer and I will mark it off. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The sinon framework](https://sinonjs.org/) might be worth considering for this, as it allows you to create spies of functions in your application logic which you can then query during testing to determine if, how, and how often those spies where called.

In the case of your code, you could create a spy "stub" of the `savePost()` function, and then use sinon to determine the number of times that the `savePost()` stub was called by `handlePosts()`. The sinon framework [provides assertion methods](https://sinonjs.org/releases/v7.2.4/mocks/#expectations) such as `expectation.exactly()` which is the way you can determine the number of times a stub was called during the unit test.

You'll need to make some adjustments to your code to integrate sinon and get everything working together. I'm not sure what constraints you're currently working with in your code base, however one approach to integrating sinon with your code might be as follows:

#### App.js

```
function savePost(post) {
    console.log("save post", post);
}

function handlePosts() {
    var posts = [
        { id: 23, title: "Me Gusta JS" },
        { id: 52, title: "Ciudad Código" },
        { id: 105, title: "Programar Ya" }
    ];

    for (var i = 0; i < posts.length; i++) {

        /* Important to ensure handlePosts() invokes savePost() via the 
        exported module to enable the stubbing "replacement" and subsequent
        callCount() assertion to work correctly */
        module.exports.savePost(posts[i]);
    }
}

module.exports = {
    savePost,
    handlePosts
};
```

#### Test.js

```
const sinon = require("sinon");

/* Import the app module shown above */
const App = require("./app");

describe("forEach", function () {

    var stubSavePost;

    before(() => {
        /* Setup the savePost stub for use in unit test before it runs. Notice
        the stub is created via the App object that is basically the 
        module.exports object of the app.js module above */
        stubSavePost = sinon.stub(App, "savePost");
    });

    after(() => {
        /* Restore the original state of your application logic, removing
        all stubs, etc after unit test complete */
        sinon.restore();
    });

    it("forEach is calling savePost three times", () => {

        /* Call handlePosts() via the exported App module object in app.js */
        App.handlePosts();

        /* Use callCount assertion from sinon to verify our savePost stub
        was called exactly three times */
        sinon.assert.callCount(stubSavePost, 3);

    });
});
```

Hope this helps!